# Xamarin Android Native bindings Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 'Failed resolution of: [Lkotlin/reflect/KProperty;'

Tags: c#, android, kotlin, xamarin.android, aar

I'm binding Stripe's android library in Xamarin.Android.
I succeeded in creating the binding project and building it finally after a lot of error resolutions.
Now, when I want to use the library I finally built in my project, I get this error without any additional information:

> Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 'Failed resolution of: [Lkotlin/reflect/KProperty;'

I added the .aar library in my android project and set the build property to Androidaarlibrary, and referenced the binding project directly from the .dll created, but nothing worked. I tried everything I could find but nothing worked.

I have added the dependencies found in the kotlin library, as you can see below:
[image]

Here is what I added as dependencies in the xamarin binding project:

[image]

I really don't know what else to try, can someone help please ?

Answer (score 2):

if you bind .aar or .jar file contain kotlin source code, you need install `Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib` on your xamarin project via `nuget`, plz install this [Link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib/1.3.50.1) on your project and then build your project, maybe this way work for you.

[image]

even you can send your .aar file to my email address, and i can bind for you, or test .dll file on my project.

Comment: Hello, thanks for this, but I added it and it doesn't work. I don't know how to get your email address but heere is a link to the .aar file, I could send you the content of my metadata.xml too, in case you need it: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/releases/download/v14.4.1/stripe-android-14.4.1.aar

Comment: ok, i bind your .aar file, and send your metadata.xml to my email, taherfattahi11@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks, I'll send it now

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to use the Stripe payment platform , right ? Fortunately ,it is available in nuget . You could check from the [Github Project Site](https://github.com/NAXAM/stripe-android-binding) .
 And you could refer the demo from https://github.com/NAXAM/stripe-android-binding/tree/master/Demo .

Comment: THanks, but I went through that library already and it is deprecated, It doesn't work properly with the current 3ds2 standards and payment intentd. And several requests for update have been made on the repository unsuccessfully, I then decided to build it myself

Comment: Xamarin Binding tool will have some known issue when binding some kotlin and swift library . SO it would be better to use the existing plugin or library .

Comment: thanks, I've checked stripe.net but it doesnt have client side mobile payment functionalities

Comment: There are lots of existing binding library , you could have a check from nuget .

Comment: I added a  xamarin kotlin package and other xamarin equivalent packages that the kotlin library target, It made this error message disapear, but another similar error apeared, and I still dont know how to resolve it

Comment: Thanks, I'll appreciate if you posted it, but the answer above yours is what helped me understand that xamarin.kotlin.stdlib was missing thus more helpful, If I accept your answer it might be miss leading for any person who might face this issue

Comment: @JohnCode have you checked Xamarin.JudoPay? according to JudoPay doc(https://docs.judopay.com/#3d-secure-2-0), it's supporting 3d secure 2.0 in latest version, and it' s nuget package is well maintained

Comment: @JohnCode so, does it surffice your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

The NAXAM's binding project mentioned in the last answer is outdated.
I'm in the same situation, so I've tried to do my own binding and after two weeks of work resolving binding errors (both compile and run time) I finally gave up on that approach.

Now we are using the http API from stripe, and making some calls directly from the server, because you cannot authenticate against the stripe service from the client, specially if you need to comply with SCA and 3DSecure and all that new stuff.

So my recommendation will be to use the API as it is instructed here:
https://stripe.com/docs/api

PRO tip (kind of...): You can still use the old bindings to implement the nice views that Stripe is provinding to enter the card information and to do the client verification of the entered number.

PRO tip 2: There is a channel where the Stripe employees will answer and help you with any doubt, they really know their jobs, are willing to help everybody and there is always someone answering your questions (This channel was a treasure really hard to find): https://freenode.logbot.info/stripe